# in indexed assignment of matrix, last lhs index must be ()

Tags: octave

Error: in indexed assignment of matrix, last lhs index must be ()
This is Octave language.

```
for(ii=1:1:10)
      Ts=5
      m(ii).x=ii*8
      m(ii).z=ii*19

      if (ii>=2)
          m(ii).xdot=(m(ii).x-m(ii-1).x)/Ts;
      end
end
```

How can I improved?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Your code runs as expected for me.

Comment: why use structures instead of just matrices ?

Comment: See [this discussion on octave discourse](https://octave.discourse.group/t/multilevel-indexed-assignment-error-message/1217)

Answer (score 2):

You'll see this error message if `m` was set to a matrix before:

```
m = [1 2];
for(ii=1:1:10)
  Ts=5
  m(ii).x=ii*8
  m(ii).z=ii*19

  if (ii>=2)
    m(ii).xdot=(m(ii).x-m(ii-1).x)/Ts;
  end
end

Ts = 5
error: in indexed assignment of matrix, last lhs index must be ()
```

As a rule of thumb, use `clear all` first if you have effects that you don't understand or inspect the output of `whos`

Comment: Similarly, if `m` is a *scalar* at the time of struct assignment, you'll see `error: in indexed assignment of scalar, last rhs index must be ()`. To fix this, you can initialize `m` as struct: `m=struct()`.